# return type is a reference - what will happen exactly?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, return

```
LinkedList& LinkedList::operator= (const LinkedList& other)
{
    if(this == &other)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    /* some other codes if this != &other */
}
```

When the code *return* * *this* is executed, the address of *this* is being returned? Meaning the variable at the LHS receiving the value will then have the same address as *this*?

Comment: Depends on the programming language, which you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Would assume that the return value of the `=`-operator is the value `=(a,b)` returns. An example using this operator in infix notation.

```
a=b=2; //this is equivalent to a=(b=2);
print(a);
```

This code-snippet should return "2", as when b=2 is executed it returns the value on the right-hand side (or in other words, the new value of b, the left-hand side), which is then supplied as the rhs of `a=`.

So for the linked-list it would be merely returning the lhs ("this") when its already equivalent to the rhs. Probably some form of optimization by terminating the code early when it notices the operator doesn't actually have to **change** anything.

Answer (score 0):

`operator *` conventionally has the signatures

```
MyClass& operator*(MyClass *)
const MyClass& operator*(const MyClass *)
```

That is it takes a "Pointer to Type" and returns a "Reference to Type"

`this` is always a pointer, to the instance of the class that the method is running in. `*this` is thus a reference to that instance.

Note how the comparison is `(this == &other)`, it has taken the address of other to compare it with the `this` pointer.